# HTML5 - change the background color of each area

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create a background, with different areas & each area with its own background color & its own set of widgets like button & text.

I tried was able to create some areas using underline. I was able to change the color of each paragraph in each area.

How to change the background color of each area in HTML5 ?

Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:red;">Area 1</p>
</body>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:green;">Area 2</p>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:orange;">Area 3</p>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:grey;">Area 4</p>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

==================== Edit ===================

I have corrected the body tag problem. Actually I did not explain the problem correctly. I want the area between two horizontal lines in different color. I thought coloring a paragraph will solve but it does not. Please suggest how can it be done.

How can I create such similar type of layouts?

Comment: "How to change the background color of each area in HTML5 ?" > you mean, with Javascript ? HTML is only the markup: no usable as programming language.

Comment: Display block 'em all.

Comment: at line 9 you have a closing </body>.

Comment: You need to get a better grasp on layouts, and the relationships between HTML and CSS. What you have will be of no use. Perhaps indicate what layout you actually want (say, with an image) to get useful suggestions.

Comment: You are closing the `<body>` tag twice. Also, you'll probably want to use a `stylesheet` instead of using inline styles. Also, are you marking up paragraphs, or sections. If you want different sections, then you should use the appropriate tag/markup.

Comment: Your doctype is wrong, `HTML5` doctype should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I have corrected the body tag problem ... actually i did not explained the problem correctly .. i want the area between two horizontal lines in different color .. i thought coloring a paragraph will achieve it but was not successful ... please suggest how to achieve it ...

Comment: How can i create this type of layout ... ?

Comment: @Katoch, do not edit the question by fixing the error. Keep it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS to make those horizontal line like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AY44s/3/)**

CSS:

```
p {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p style="background-color:red;">Area 1
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p style="background-color:green;">Area 2
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p style="background-color:orange;">Area 3
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</p>
<p style="background-color:grey;">Area 4
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</p>
```

Comment: it worked .. css seems to be really good ..please suggest some tutorials to learn all this layout stuff ..

Comment: @Katoch There are tons of them out there... You could start looking here : http://www.csstutorial.net/ it is pretty simple to start with. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you more in fo here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just one body tag per document. Remove line 9 closing tag. Rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:red;">Area 1</p>
</body> <!-- <== this is the problem... -->
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:green;">Area 2</p>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:orange;">Area 3</p>
<hr>
<p style="background-color:grey;">Area 4</p>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```